# Transpile all TypeScript files to a relative adjacent directory

Tags: javascript, bash, typescript, typescript2.0, tsc

I am writing our JavaScript based tests with TypeScript.

I would like a single `tsc --watch` command, to be able to handle transpiling all of our files correctly, that's the key part. I think using multiple tsconfig.json files is the way to go here.

I have this structure:

```
/tests
  /e2e
     tsconfig.json
    /src
    /target
  /unit
     tsconfig.json
    /src
    /target
```

*I want to put the TypeScript files in the src directories, and transpile them into the target directories.*

My question is - if you have a bash script that can take a list of files as input, how could you transpile the files into their respective target directory?

**e.g., input files:**

```
/home/you/projects/x/test/e2e/src/a.ts
/home/you/projects/x/test/e2e/src/b.ts
/home/you/projects/x/test/e2e/src/c.ts
/home/you/projects/x/test/unit/src/foo.ts
/home/you/projects/x/test/unit/src/bar.ts
/home/you/projects/x/test/unit/src/baz.ts
```

**desired output files:**

```
/home/you/projects/x/test/e2e/target/a.js
/home/you/projects/x/test/e2e/target/b.js
/home/you/projects/x/test/e2e/target/c.js
/home/you/projects/x/test/unit/target/foo.js
/home/you/projects/x/test/unit/target/bar.js
/home/you/projects/x/test/unit/target/baz.js
```

Is there a way for the `tsc` command to take those files and transpile them all in one a one line command to their respective target directories?

I assume that might be very tricky to do. I might have to group them by their dirname, and transpile each group separately. That would be much harder.

Comment: How are you transpiling them?

Comment: there is a target dir option for the tsc that just does this, you can set it in the tsconfig.json :-/

Comment: `outDir` in tsconfig.json is what you are looking for

Comment: people, there would have to be two different outDirs, read the question carefully

Comment: "How am I transpiling them?" that is the question. I have the source, and I want to transpile all the files with one tsc command, but I do not know how to do that.

Comment: x/src/a.ts -> x/target/a.js  and y/src/b.ts -> y/target/b.js, that is what I am trying to do with tsc, in one command ideally.

Comment: what you can do is make 2 projects with different configs(easier if you use gulp/grunt) and use the `include` compiler option to include different files.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, so probably have to put different tsconfig.json files in each separate directory. I have more than two src directories, there are multiple..I just used two for brevity.

Comment: Initially I deleted the question, but then I realized that I do want a single tsc --watch command to be able to handle transpiling all the files correctly. So I just updated the question. I think using multiple tsconfig.json files in each subdirectory is the best solution. But not 100% sure yet.

Comment: So after some investigation, running tsc -w from the root of the project, with multiple tsconfig.json files in different subdirectories - it appears that tsc -w just picks up the tsconfig.json file in the root of the project and applies that only. Will file an issue with TS on Github.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16604

Comment: why not just run two watchers? you can make it a one liner with a regular bash '&'.

Comment: yeah that's what I have done, I run a watcher for each different tsconfig.js file. https://github.com/ORESoftware/tsc-multi-watch

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get the native `tsc --watch` to support that project structure, but you can using [gulp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp) and [gulp-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-typescript).   They permit you to setup simultaneous watches on several different TypeScript projects, each with their own **tsconfig.json**.

If there are dependencies between those subdirectories, consider using [lerna](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lerna) as well.   Otherwise you may end up with a surprising layout in your target directories. An extra level of directories was the initial problem which got me looking into this.   With `lerna`, you will setup separate **package.json** files which document the dependencies.  Then  `lerna bootstrap` can take care of setting up symbolic links to resolve the references.

With `lerna`, you may want to mark some of the **package.json** files as `"private": true`, if they are not intended to be published to npm.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to probably end up writing something that basically spawns a "tsc -w" for each tsconfig.json file.

Answer (score 0):

I created a tool to do this:

[github.com/ORESoftware/tsc-multi-watch](http://github.com/ORESoftware/tsc-multi-watch)

It will search your project for `/tsconfig.*\.json/` files, and spawn a tsc -w process for each one.

Not only that but it solves another deficiency of tsc --watch. tsc --watch cannot account for new files that are added to the project.

tsc-multi-watch will restart the correct `tsc -w` process when a `.ts` file is added to the project.

Comment: Looks good, but it's still a petty tsc doesn't support this natively because any solution spawning separate tsc processes will scale poorly in a larger-scale project, hitting CPU and memory with overhead.

Comment: yes still a *pity..I agree, there's not great solution, but I think multiple tsc processes each watching 8 files is not much worse than 1 tsc process watching 64 files, etc. They are mostly idling.